# How to mathematicaly prove the Time Complexity of the recursive Fibonacci program with Memoization

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, fibonacci, memoization

Well, I am looking for a more mathematical approach to things.
Using this two-analysis approach.

For the standard Fibonacci recursive function, we all know that it runs with time complexity **O(2^n)**
the proof found by upper bound :

```
T(n-1)=T(n-2)

T(n)=2T(n-1)+c   

    =4T(n-2)+3c

    =8T(n-3)+7c

    =2^k T(n-k)+(2^k-1)c

n - k = 0 , hence k = n

T(n) = 2^n T(0) + (2^n - 1)c

T(n) = (1 + c) * 2^n - c

T(n) <= 2^n
```

I tried to optimize this time, I used the *Memoization* approach of Dynamic Programming in the following code :

```
private static long fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    
    if (memo[n] != 0) {
        return memo[n];
    }
    
    long result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    memo[n] = result;
    
    return result;
}
```

I know that looking at, and by trying some n the n value; this code is much better. And also that the time complexity dropped to **O(n)**.

I want to do the same proof thing for this code using upper/lower bounds to prove this, but I don't know how to start.

The thing to say, I am doing this to see where my worst and best scenarios are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between the elements of the sequence doesn't change. *T(n)* would be still expressed in the same way:

*T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2)*

And

*T(n - 1) = T(n - 2) + T(n - 3)*

And

*T(n - 2) = T(n - 3) + T(n - 4)*

And so on, until recursion hit the base case: *T(0) = c* and *T(1) = c*.

What changes when you're applying Memoization is the number of recursive calls. It would be ***2 * n*** instead of ***2<sup>n</sup>***. And every repeated recursive call (like *T(n - 2)* and *T(n - 3)* above) would now have a constant time complexity.

It would be more apparent if you would draw a tree of recursive calls on a paper, then you would observe that branches on one side of the tree turned into a leaves (because the result of these calls was already computed, and we don't propagate them further).

Here's such a tree of call for plain recursion:

```
                t(n)   Naive reqursive implementation
               /    \  2 ^ n recursive calls
              /      \
           t(n-1)    t(n-2)
          /   \        /  \
         /     \      /    \
   t(n-2)   t(n-3)  t(n-3)  t(n-4)
   /   \     /  \    /  \    /  \
  .................................
   t(2)
  /   \
t(1)  t(0)
```

And that's how it changes if we apply Memoization:

```
                t(n)   Memoization
               /    \  ~ 2 * n recursive calls
              /      \
           t(n-1)    t(n-2)
           /   \
          /     \
     t(n-2)    t(n-3)
     /   \ 
  .................................
   t(2)
  /   \
t(1)  t(0)
```

I.e.

*T(n) = T(n - 1) + c = T(n - 2) + 2 * c = T(n - 3) + 3 * c = ... = T(1) + n * c*

Which would give *T(n) = O(n)*